# Delete all empty folder recursively via the command line

Tags: filesystem

I have a mono app and it delete all empty folders in a folder tree.

Is there a way to do this via the command line? The idea is that I would call it as an external process.

I had tried this:

```
sudo rm r <folder>
```

but it deletes folders that have files in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question but rather a Linux/Unix command line question here is how I do it:

```
find <folder> -type d -empty -delete
```

in words: Find all file system entries in `<folder>` of type directory which is empty and go delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I would move it to the correct board but as you kindly answered I will not. Thanks again :)